# How to access a class variable from same class

Tags: php, class, oop, variables

In this snippet:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product_variant extends Model
{

    protected $primaryKey='variant_id';

    public $translationForeignKey = $this->primaryKey;
}
```

This rule is not working:

```
public $translationForeignKey = $this->primaryKey;
```

How can we access this variable that is in the same scope of this class?

Comment: Just an observations : I would have expected `Product_variant` to extend `Product`

Comment: You need to assign the properties value in the constructor, via a setter method or by setting the property _after_ the class has been instantiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either set the value in a constructor or create a getter to return the value.

// option 1

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product_variant extends Model
{

    protected $primaryKey='variant_id';

    public $translationForeignKey = '';

    // option 1
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->translationForeignKey = $this->primaryKey;
    }

}
```

// option 2, you dont even need the other property in this method, unless its value may change during execution

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product_variant extends Model
{

    protected $primaryKey='variant_id';

    // option 2
    public function getTranslationForeignKey()
    {
         return $this->primaryKey;
    }

}
```

Comment: Just remove the `$` after `$this->` :)

Comment: @AshwiniAgarwal Thanks, copy/paste will get you _Every Time_

Answer (score 1):

At the time of defining the class you can only assign constant values to the class properties. Variables are not allowed here.

You need to do assignment part in the constructor.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product_variant extends Model
{

    protected $primaryKey='variant_id';

    public $translationForeignKey;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->translationForeignKey = $this->primaryKey;
    }
}
```